# What is the name of the Logical fallacy that states There was a good outcome once, therefore the problem no longer exists?

Tags: fallacies

Example. Obama elected president therefore racism no longer exists in USA.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inadequately small sample fallacy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/52724/inadequately-small-sample-fallacy)

Comment: I think this is a bad example. A black person can win 51% of the votes if 49% are racists and therefore against him.

Comment: ""America can't be racist because it elected two Black people who half the country hates for reasons they can't quite put their finger on" -Trevor Noah framing the fallacy